# How can we synchronize image size and src when loading dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have a function that updates an image by changing the src and css (width/height) of an IMG tag in the document. Here's a simplified version for illustration:

```
changeImage = function(src,width,height) {
  $("#changethis").attr("src",src).css("width",width+"px").css("height",height+"px");
}

<img id="changethis" />

<input type="button" onClick="changeImage('image1.jpg',100,150);" />
<input type="button" onClick="changeImage('image2.jpg',185,200);" />
<input type="button" onClick="changeImage('image3.jpg',50,100);" />
```

The problem is that either src OR css will change first, creating an awkward stretch effect since the images are all different sizes. What's the best way around this?

Please note that I already tried hiding/re-showing the img before/after making the changes. No luck. Hope someone smarter than me can help! :)

Comment: have you tried removing the width and height before the update?

Comment: Firstly you should change HTML code to onClick="changeImage('image1.jpg',100,150);", because quota is not correct.

Comment: @jackJoe: no. nice idea. i'll try that and post my results. thank you.

Comment: @Evgeniy: that was just sample code, but of course you're right. sample code fixed. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the `src` attribute of an image, it will always show the original src until the new image has finished loading. I would recommend that you replace the entire image element instead of changing the `src` attribute.

```
changeImage = function(src, width, height) {
    $("#changethis").replaceWith(
        '<img id="changethis" src="' + src + '" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" />'
    );
};
```

Comment: this worked better than i expected. i'd already tried a similar approach, using html("<img ... />") on the parent div, but it responded sluggishly. replaceWith("<img ... />") worked much better and was pretty straightforward. thank you!

Comment: @Fibbe: thanks to Fibbe for the first response and pre-loading suggestion. i tried Fibbe's method first, and it also worked perfectly. i 'm going to accept nderscore's answer, but i'll probably implement some kind of pre-loading routine as well. thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

There is a loading time for the image, if it's not cached.

Solution, preload the image:

```
changeImage = function(src,width,height) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
     $("#changethis").attr("src",src).css("width",width+"px").css("height",height+"px");
  };
  img.src = src;
}
```

Comment: If you set the src last, you can be sure it will always work even on cached images. As you have it, once the image is cached, the function won't do anything on additional calls in some browsers due to the onload event never being triggered.

Comment: That's true, usually it works because it's fast enough to attach the handler before it loads from cache. But maybe on older browsers where JS is slower it wont work.

Comment: It's primarily an issue with older versions of IE where if the image is cached, it will immediately run onload event synchronously, before you bind to it.

Comment: Oh okay, nice you saw it!

Comment: @Fibbe: awesome! i'll try this too and post my results today. thank you.

Comment: also, not sure if it was just my imagination or not, but your solution worked better when attr("src",src) was changed to attr("src",img.src). that way, it referenced the just-loaded new Image instead of the function parameter. does that make sense?

Comment: another optimization to this method... if you initialize "var img;" outside of the function and just have "img = new Image();" inside the function, performance improves noticeably. i don't understand why, since you're still creating a new Image object each time the function runs, but it made quite a difference.